# Visual Studio - Breakpoint in lambda function wrapped with macro does not break

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lambda, macros, breakpoints

I try to put a breakpoint in the lambda function wrapped with a macro but it does not break at all (first breakpoint in the attached image).
Instead, using the function defined in the outside of the macro it breaks without problem (second breakpoint in the attached image), but I don't want to introduce the auxiliary variable for this if possible.

It it a correct behavior or a bug?

Checked with VS2015 community edition.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CALL(Lambda) Lambda();

int main()
{
    CALL([]()
    {
        std::cout << "hello 1" << std::endl;
    });

    const auto f = []()
    {
        std::cout << "hello 2" << std::endl;
    };
    CALL(f);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Image: two breakpoints, first one does not break, second one breaks]

Comment: I imagine it is because whole macro expression is replaced and therefore it is not the same code where you have set breakpoint. Remember, macro arguments are not code. It is simply text. It will become code later when macro is replaced with its content. I believe, you can only place brekpoint on macro itself (line where `CALL` is written)

Comment: confirmed - breakpoint works if you remove the ridiculous macro.